# Making a jQuery plugin work in wordpress - "thumbanail grid expanding preview"

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have found a superb jquery tutorial [here](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/03/19/thumbnail-grid-with-expanding-preview/).
But now I'm trying to make it run in wordpress but I cant seem to get the jquery to work!!

I'm enqueue the script like this in my functions.php:

```
wp_register_script( 'grid-js', 
   get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/library/js/grid.js', 
   array( 'jquery' ), '', true );
   wp_enqueue_script( 'grid-js' );
```

and I've put the whole grid.js inside this code so I dont have any $ conflicts:

```
(function($) { ...code here... })(jQuery);
```

In the tutorial there is a  tag at the bottom of the index.html page which fires up the jquery file. I've put this at the bottom of my index page like so:

```
 <script>
    (function($) {
    Grid.init();
    })(jQuery); </script>
```

But all I get is this error message.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Grid is not defined

Hopefully in the long run I will load the expanding grid via an ajax call, but for now I'm only looking at actually getting the Jquery to work in wordpress.

If anyone has any pointers or a tutorial of how to get jquery plugins to work in wordpress that would be great and I'm sure others would appreciate it. I've spent many hours searching on here and google but I've not come up with anything good so far most of the tutorials are about enqueing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I've managed to implement this to work.

what I did was to put:

```
(function($) {

$(function() {
    grids.init();
    });

})(jQuery);
```

on its own js file called it loadgrid.js and registered the script to load in my functions.php

```
wp_register_script( 'loadgrid', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/library/js/loadgrid.js', array( 'grid-js' ), false , true );
```

for some reason I was unable to put it inline, but doing it this way worked as its loaded at the bottom of the page on register.

hope this helps